# javascript-переменные и IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Это прикол, да, в IE? (у меня 8й).

```
someItem = document.getElementById('someItem')
```

Этот код выдает ошибку. Какой недоумок-программист  запретил использование переменной, совпадающей с id элемента?? Или я чтоо-то не так понял?

Comment: Смотрите внимательней свой код.

Данный скрипт будет искать не переменную `someItem`, а элемент с `id someItem`

Comment: Конечно, и при этом выдавать ошибку. Никогда не проверял код сайтов в ie
И вот - проверил. У меня обычный код. Работает везде. Запустил в ie- тут же ошибка! Изменил имя переменной - все заработало. что за фигня?

Comment: @lampa, конкретно выдает `Object doesn't support this property or method`

Comment: а что за ошибка? Мне кажется, что проблема не в том, что переменная и элемент имеют одинаковые названия.

Comment: @Deus попробуйте объявлять переменные с помощью `var`.

Comment: Все , проверил. Это самый идиотский баг, который я когда-либо видел. Если указывать var перед переменной, все работает. Но, позвольте, тогда такую конструкцию нельзя будет использовать в функциях! Ибо переменная не будет глобальной.

Comment: Как известно, глобальные переменные это зло. И функция не должна изменять переменные, которые передаются ей как параметры. Так что это очень правильный шаг со стороны разработчиков IE.

Comment: @KryDos, предупредили бы как-то, что-ли. Пока сам не наступишь, не узнаешь. Вообще-то я ВСЕГДА объявлял переменные через var. Вот один раз не указал ключевое слово - и на тебе. Хорошо, что код небольшой, легко подправить.))

Comment: @KryDos, код, вызвавший ошибку был в ГЛОБАЛЬНОЙ ОБЛАСТИ, а не в функции

Comment: @Deus, ну что ж вы так. Приучите винить себя в первую очередь, потому что это уже не первый ваш вопрос на который я отвечаю и почти в каждом вопросе вы вините либо сервер либо интерпретатор, либо разработчиков библиотек, либо разработчиков браузера. Это не есть хорошо, потому что обычный и правильный ход мыслей - это: "**Ох, что-то не работает. Наверное Я ЧТО-ТО ПРОПУСТИЛ ИЛИ НЕ ДОГЛЯДЕЛ В ДОКУМЕНТАЦИИ. Нужно посмотреть все более детально.**". Причем попутно вы еще узнаете огромное количество новой информации :) 

А у вас совсем не так вопросы построены :(

Comment: Кстати в офф. документации на сайте майкрософта написано следующие:
"Use the **var** statement to declare variables". Так что вас предупреждали. Это просто вы не доглядели :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/z16cackw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

Comment: Вопрос был не в том, а МОЖНО ли объявлять переменные без инструкции var, и приведет ли это к перезаписи глобальных переменных, а в том, что ie ДОПУСКАЕТ  данное использование переменных, но - факт - при совпадении их имен с id-значениями, это вызывает ФАТАЛЬНУЮ ошибку. Исключение. Останов программы.!

Comment: отчего вы вообще решили завести переменную в глобальной области ? я может 3-4 случая знаю когда это необходимо, из реального мира это как-бы если бы вы решили повесить объявление о продаже советской стиральной машины на медного всадника.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То, что вы называете глобальной переменной таковой не является. Выполнение скрипта идет в контексте окна (объекта window). Присваивание (без var) `x = 0` создает свойство у объекта window с именем x. В IE (и с некоторых пор в других браузерах) все элементы документа с указанными id доступны как "глобальные" переменные, т.е. как свойства объекта window. То, что ошибка возникает только в IE8, а, например, в IE9 ваше присваивание срабатывает как и вы и ожидаете - это лишь реализация в конкретной версии браузера. В 8й версии когда вы пытаетесь перезаписать свойство, указывающее на элемент DOM, возникает исключение, сеттер не реализован просто видимо.

Попробуйте выполнить такой код:

```
alert = 0;
```

Да, IE8 выдаст такую же ошибку. В IE9 и других бразуерах alert работать больше не будет и перестанет как и ожидается быть функцией.

ЗЫ Почему использовать эти "глобальные" переменные плохо, думаю, понятно. 
ЗЗЫ А разработчиков IE не надо пинать, их уже и так прокляли несколько поколений web-девелоперов, от еще одного проклятья им уже разницы нет.

Comment: Спасибо за вразумительный ответ. А "глобальной переменной" я назвал переменную, которая глобальна относительно объекта windows, т.е. не может быть переопределена в функции посредством инструкции var. Удивляет одно, что в таком серьезном вопросе как namespace браузеры настолько неоднозначны.

Comment: @eicto, вообще у меня когда-то был код такого рода, что в html файле в теге body было только объявление пустых дивов с их ай-ди, а остальное делал джава-скрипт код. В коде объявлялись глобальные переменные, содержащие ссылки на дом-объекты, так, чтобы в функциях было проще к ним обращаться. А что, нельзя?

Comment: нельзя глобальные, я уже объяснил почему, к тому-же как вам теперь известно `<div id="mydiv">` порождает переменную window.mydiv, которая без объявления `var` - глобальная в вашем конкретном случае, это присваивание вообще не нужно someItem и без того ссылается на ваш элемент.

Comment: @eicto, неувязка в том, что про "рождение" переменных при создании элемента  <div id="mydiv">, я узнаю только на hashcode.ru . А вокруг тишина... А про медного всадника - почему, если стопицот функций постоянно  используют какой-то объект DOM или какую-то константу, эти сущности нельзя объявить в глобальной области видимости? Особенно касается констант.

Comment: Ну, это беда многих - замена чтения документации самодеятельностью и вопросами на форумах :) А ведь там предупреждали английским по белому: "You can declare a variable without using the var keyword and assign a value to it. This is known as an implicit declaration, and it is not recommended. An implicit declaration gives the variable global scope. When you declare a variable at the procedure level, though, you typically do not want it to have global scope. To avoid giving the variable global scope, you must use the var keyword in your variable declaration."

Comment: @klopp, это беда многих, только не моя. И про var знаем, и т.д. (Тем более "You can declare a variable without using the var keyword"). Вы мой вопрос видели? Как я мог догадаться, что  <div id="mydiv"> порождает переменную window.mydiv? Спасибо некоторым ребятам, которые на это указали. В отличие от некоторых, которые пытались меня уразумить о нецелесообразности объявления глобальных переменных.

Comment: Есть такая штука, best practice. Применительно к данному случаю - всегда использовать var, всегда использовать точку с запятой и т.д. Следование "хорошей практике" снимает массу вопросов сразу же. А узнавать про неё и про поведение переменных нужно, как ни странно, из документации и учебников. Про использование глобальных переменных - тоже из книжек, про программирование :) Убеждать же в том, что небо синее а трава зелёная человека, у которого нет цветового зрения, я не вижу большого смысла, про это и так тонны слов написаны в общедоступных источниках...

Comment: @Deus в js нигде, [кроме firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), [констант нет](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130396/are-there-constants-in-javascript)